# TypeScript: Exporting complex interface

Tags: typescript

please have a look at code below:

```
enum ActionTypeEnum {
  GET_WAREHOUSE_ITEM_LIST_INITIAL = 'GET_WAREHOUSE_ITEM_LIST_INITIAL',
  GET_BASKET = 'GET_BASKET',
}    
interface Action {
    type: ActionTypeEnum,
}

export {ActionTypeEnum};  // works fine
export {Action};          //Cannot re-export a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

As far as I understand it is possible to export `ActionTypeEnum` because it does not depend on anything.
As far as I understand it is not possible to export `Action` because it uses `ActionTypeEnum` and cannot be exported on it's own.

Please tell me how to export `Action` and if my understanding of the problem is correct.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This GitHub issue explores the topic](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32662). The compiler complains when:

1. we use `isolatedModules` and
2. we use `export { SomeThing }` with either a `type` or an `interface`.

This happens because, with isolated modules, each module is isolated, which makes it hard for transpilers like `babel` to decide whether `SomeThing` has a JavaScript representation. If `SomeThing` is a class, a function, or an object, then the transpiler needs to represent it in JavaScript. On the other hand, if `SomeThing` is a `type` or an `interface`, then the transpiler must not represent it in JavaScript.

What to do?

One option is an inline `export interface SomeThing { }` statement like this:

```
enum ActionTypeEnum1 {
  // ...
}

export interface Action1 { // <-------- inline export
  type: ActionTypeEnum1;
}

export { ActionTypeEnum1 };
```

If you are using **TypeScript 3.8+**, another option is to use `export type { SomeThing }` like this:

```
enum ActionTypeEnum2 {
  // ...
}

interface Action2 {
  type: ActionTypeEnum2;
}

export type { Action2 } // <-------- export type { }
export { ActionTypeEnum2 }
```

Comment: I get `'Action2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` error now :-(

Comment: @JacekWojcik What version of TypeScript are you running? `export type { }` syntax requires TypeScript `3.8` or greater.

Comment: >tsc --version
Version 3.8.3

Comment: I am using VS Code, dependencies: "typescript": "^3.8.3"

Comment: @JacekWojcik I am not sure how else I can help. Perhaps you could push a simple example to a GitHub repository to help us reproduce the error. In the meantime, here is the example in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYBRcCAJigG8AoKKAemqgDpHyBfc8pEBYAJwDMBDOMFiJUIEhSoIcwAFwjkaLLgKQiAbhZtgAD2wpuCKNNxkFYksxp0APAFoHjh1F37DxmWdauDR0uaUZVWIoZiA